# Google Translate API returns 403 (PHP)

Tags: php, google-api, google-translate

The question is about Google Translate API

1. I set a project and turn the billing on (with some money on the account)
2. I created a key for server app (also tryed to use a browser key) and added all 3 IPs I have (home and 2 servers)

**What I see:**

1. It does work in apis-explorer and in a browser address bar (https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/detect?q=an%20english%20text&key=MY_KEY)
2. It returns 403 error if I trying to get the same URL from PHP code:

   $apiKey = 'MY_KEY';

   $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/detect?q=an%20english%20text&key=' . $apiKey . '';

   $handle = curl_init($url);

   curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

   $response = curl_exec($handle);

   curl_close($handle);

   print_r(json_decode($response, true));

**thre result:**

```
Array (
    [error] => Array (
            [errors] => Array (
                    [0] => Array (
                            [domain] => usageLimits
                            [reason] => ipRefererBlocked
                            [message] => There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.
                            [extendedHelp] => https://console.developers.google.com
                        ))
            [code] => 403
            [message] => There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.
        ))
```

I checked the IPs dozens of times, tryed to use browser key with allowed URL as referer.
Out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for admins, they helped to figure out.
By default - curl using our ipv6 address...

So we have three options here:

1. curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
2. add ipv6 address to allowed list
3. Turn ipv6 off forthe server

I had to be more attentive and remember about ipv6 :-)

Comment: Thank you for details. Strange but "URL as referrer" should work... but it takes time to update.

Answer (score -2):

I am told that this is fixed by simply removing all Ip's from the edit allowed IP's option. This makes it so that **it is less secure**, but it will accept all IP's after that.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSbTL.jpg]

Comment: Sorry. This 'less secure' could hurt my wallet :-)

Comment: While a valid answer, Not recommended.. I wouldnt down vote this.. But nor would i upvote it either.